# Justifying table text to match text margins?

Tags: tables, text, justification

I have been trying to justify the text I have above all of my tables, but to no avail. Initially, I used the `\begin{flushleft}` which was a bad solution, since it left aligned the text and made it look like this:

[image]

which does not justify the text to span it to the right text margin. I also tried using the `\begin{justification}` environment, which did not help either, as it seemed to just center the text. How can I justify the text, so it mathes the text margins? I posted my code as MWE below:

```
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf}

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Valuation errors by the combinatorial selection schemes for the S\&P sub-indices}
\label{Results.Robustness.FirmSize}
\begin{flushleft} This table reports the median and arithmetic mean of the absolute percentage errors generated by the two combinatorial peer selection schemes SBP\Plus SARD and GICS\Plus SARD, for constituents of the S\&P 500, 400 and 600 indices. The median and arithmetic mean of the pairwise valuation error differences are statistically tested through the Wilcoxon signed rank test and Student's t-test, respectively. Each combinatorial selection scheme has used the EV/EBITDA, EV/EBIT and P/E multiple to value a target firm. A positive pairwise median difference indicates that the SBP\Plus SARD generates a higher valuation accuracy, relative to GICS\Plus SARD, and vice versa. Statistical significance is denoted by *, **, *** indicating 10\%, 5\% and 1\% respectively. \\ 
\end{flushleft} \vspace{0.2cm}
\begin{tabular}{|lccc|}
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{003085} 
{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{S\&P 500}} & {\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Median}} & {\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Mean}} & {\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{IQ range}} \\
\textbf{EV/EBITDA} &  &  &  \\
GICS+SARD & 25.1\% (2) & 31.5\% (2) & 34.2\% (2) \\
SBP+SARD & 20.7\% (1) & 27.9\% (1) & 27.4\% (1) \\
Pairwise difference & \textbf{4.2\%***} & \textbf{3.5\%***} &  \\
\textbf{EV/EBIT} &  &  &  \\
GICS+SARD & 23.7\% (2) & 29.6\% (2) & 31.4\% (2) \\
SBP+SARD & 20.5\% (1) & 27.5\% (1) & 28.2\% (1) \\
Pairwise difference & \textbf{2.5\%***} & \textbf{2.0\%***} &  \\
\textbf{P/E} &  &  &  \\
GICS+SARD & 30.5\% (2) & 42.2\% (2) & 45.6\% (2) \\
SBP+SARD & 27.7\% (1) & 39.2\% (1) & 41.2\% (1) \\
Pairwise difference & \textbf{3.3\%***} & \textbf{3.0\%***} &  \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{003085} 
{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{S\&P 400}} & {\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Median}} & {\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Mean}} & {\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{IQ range}} \\
\textbf{EV/EBITDA} &  &  &  \\
GICS+SARD & 27.7\% (2) & 42.4\% (2) & 36.6\% (2) \\
SBP+SARD & 24.8\% (1) & 33.1\% (1) & 34.3\% (1) \\
Pairwise difference & \textbf{2.9\%***} & \textbf{10.3\%***} &  \\
\textbf{EV/EBIT} &  &  &  \\
GICS+SARD & 30.8\% (2) & 44.5\% (2) & 39.6\% (2) \\
SBP+SARD & 25.3\% (1) & 34.2\% (1) & 33.2\% (1) \\
Pairwise difference & \textbf{5.9\%***} & \textbf{2.0\%***} &  \\
\textbf{P/E} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\
GICS+SARD & \multicolumn{1}{l}{40.0\% (2)} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{52.6\% (2)} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{55.7\% (2)} \\
SBP+SARD & \multicolumn{1}{l}{34.1\% (1)} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{48.9\% (1)} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{45.9\% (1)} \\
Pairwise difference & \textbf{6.2\%***} & \textbf{3.6\%***} &  \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{003085} 
{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{S\&P 600}} & {\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Median}} & {\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Mean}} & {\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{IQ range}} \\ \hline
\textbf{EV/EBITDA} &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\
GICS+SARD & 28.2\% (2) & 40.0\% (2) & 36.1\% (2) \\
SBP+SARD & 24.6\% (1) & 31.3\% (1) & 32.1\% (1) \\
Pairwise difference & \textbf{3.9\%***} & \textbf{8.7\%***} &  \\
\textbf{EV/EBIT} &  &  &  \\
GICS+SARD & 27.1\% (2) & 36.3\% (2) & 36.3\% (2) \\
SBP+SARD & 25.3\% (1) & 31.7\% (1) & 33.9\% (1) \\
Pairwise difference & \textbf{2.7\%***} & \textbf{4.6\%***} &  \\
\textbf{P/E} &  &  &  \\
GICS+SARD & 33.4\% (2) & 45.6\% (2) & 43.7\% (2) \\
SBP+SARD & 30.5\% (1) & 37.8\% (1) & 37.9\% (1) \\
Pairwise difference & \textbf{4.6\%***} & \textbf{7.8\%***} &  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use the `flushleft` environment for a justified text!

Comment: Please provide a full example that actually compiles

Comment: I see you edited your question.  However, there is still no `\documentclass`, and `\usepackage` appears after `\begin{document}` (not allowed), and `\smaller` is still not defined.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes - I edited the code. My bad for wrongfully placement. It works now as an MWE for me.

Comment: There is still no `\documentclass` provided, and `\Plus` is not defined.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes - Corrected, but I thought it was only necessary to post a minimum working environment, i.e. a compilable code.

Comment: A Minimum Working Example (MWE) includes everything from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`.  That is the standard expected of questioners.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes - Thank you for the clarification :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your text inside a `\parbox` to neutralise the `centering` command. I took the opportunity to add some improvements to the table layout:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{relsize}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\smaller
\caption{Valuation errors by the combinatorial selection schemes for the S\&P sub-indices}
\label{Results.Robustness.FirmSize}\medskip
\parbox{\textwidth}{This table reports the median and arithmetic mean of the absolute percentage errors generated by the two combinatorial peer selection schemes SBP+SARD and GICS+SARD, for constituents of the S\&P 500, 400 and 600 indices. The median and arithmetic mean of the pairwise valuation error differences are statistically tested through the Wilcoxon signed rank test and Student's t-test, respectively. Each combinatorial selection scheme has used the EV/EBITDA, EV/EBIT and P/E multiple to value a target firm. A positive pairwise median difference indicates that the SBP+SARD generates a higher valuation accuracy, relative to GICS+SARD, and vice versa. Statistical significance is denoted by *, **, *** indicating 10\%, 5\% and 1\% respectively.}
 \vspace{0.2cm}

\begin{tabular}{|lccc|}
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{003085}
{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{S\&P 500}} & {\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Median}} & {\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Mean}} & {\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{IQ range}} \\
\textbf{EV/EBITDA} & & & \\
GICS+SARD & 25.1\% (2) & 31.5\% (2) & 34.2\% (2) \\
SBP+SARD & 20.7\% (1) & 27.9\% (1) & 27.4\% (1) \\
Pairwise difference & \textbf{4.2\%***} & \textbf{3.5\%***} & \\
\textbf{EV/EBIT} & & & \\
GICS+SARD & 23.7\% (2) & 29.6\% (2) & 31.4\% (2) \\
SBP+SARD & 20.5\% (1) & 27.5\% (1) & 28.2\% (1) \\
Pairwise difference & \textbf{2.5\%***} & \textbf{2.0\%***} & \\
\textbf{P/E} & & & \\
GICS+SARD & 30.5\% (2) & 42.2\% (2) & 45.6\% (2) \\
SBP+SARD & 27.7\% (1) & 39.2\% (1) & 41.2\% (1) \\
Pairwise difference & \textbf{3.3\%***} & \textbf{3.0\%***} & \\[1ex]
\rowcolor[HTML]{003085}
{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{S\&P 400}} & {\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Median}} & {\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Mean}} & {\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{IQ range}} \\
\textbf{EV/EBITDA} & & & \\
GICS+SARD & 27.7\% (2) & 42.4\% (2) & 36.6\% (2) \\
SBP+SARD & 24.8\% (1) & 33.1\% (1) & 34.3\% (1) \\
Pairwise difference & \textbf{2.9\%***} & \textbf{10.3\%***} & \\
\textbf{EV/EBIT} & & & \\
GICS+SARD & 30.8\% (2) & 44.5\% (2) & 39.6\% (2) \\
SBP+SARD & 25.3\% (1) & 34.2\% (1) & 33.2\% (1) \\
Pairwise difference & \textbf{5.9\%***} & \textbf{2.0\%***} & \\
\textbf{P/E} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\
GICS+SARD & \multicolumn{1}{l}{40.0\% (2)} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{52.6\% (2)} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{55.7\% (2)} \\
SBP+SARD & \multicolumn{1}{l}{34.1\% (1)} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{48.9\% (1)} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{45.9\% (1)} \\
Pairwise difference & \textbf{6.2\%***} & \textbf{3.6\%***} & \\[1ex] \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{003085}
{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{S\&P 600}} & {\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Median}} & {\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Mean}} & {\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{IQ range}} \\ \hline
\textbf{EV/EBITDA} & & & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\
GICS+SARD & 28.2\% (2) & 40.0\% (2) & 36.1\% (2) \\
SBP+SARD & 24.6\% (1) & 31.3\% (1) & 32.1\% (1) \\
Pairwise difference & \textbf{3.9\%***} & \textbf{8.7\%***} & \\
\textbf{EV/EBIT} & & & \\
GICS+SARD & 27.1\% (2) & 36.3\% (2) & 36.3\% (2) \\
SBP+SARD & 25.3\% (1) & 31.7\% (1) & 33.9\% (1) \\
Pairwise difference & \textbf{2.7\%***} & \textbf{4.6\%***} & \\
\textbf{P/E} & & & \\
GICS+SARD & 33.4\% (2) & 45.6\% (2) & 43.7\% (2) \\
SBP+SARD & 30.5\% (1) & 37.8\% (1) & 37.9\% (1) \\
Pairwise difference & \textbf{4.6\%***} & \textbf{7.8\%***} & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]